# Bucket sort in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, sorting

As a first step in learning Haskell I am solving [this problem](http://ipsc.ksp.sk/1999/practice/problems/j.html), which involves finding the *R<sub>i</sub>*<sup>th</sup>-ranked numbers, given some input list and many *R<sub>i</sub>*. In an imperative language I would make a zeroed array c of length 200, increment c[h] for each height h, compute cumulative sums of c and then binary search c to determine the height corresponding to each given index. Because max_height is fixed, this has runtime linear in the size of input and bounded memory(*) excluding the input.

Here's my Haskell code:

```
max_height = 200
count_eq e = foldl (\c f -> if e == f then c + 1 else c) 0
counts heights = map (flip count_eq heights) [0..max_height]
first_gt e l = f l 0 where f (x:xs) i = if x > e then i else f xs (i+1)
solve heights indices = let accum = scanl1 (+) (counts heights) in
  map (flip first_gt accum) (map (subtract 1) indices)
```

It is correct but slow. I would like to know how to (A) reason about and (B) improve the performance. Also (C) can I achieve the same asymptotic performance as the imperative code?

(*) assuming each c[i] fits in a machine int. I believe the runtime statement holds regardless.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maps as arrays

In `counts heights` you are taversing heights 200 times.
It is possible to emulate array with [`Data.IntMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-IntMap.html) and do this in one pass:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as Map

count = foldl' (\m h -> Map.insertWith (+) h 1 m)
  (Map.fromList [(i,0) | i <- [1..200]])
```

Note that I'm using *strict* version of left fold (see [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') about `foldl` vs `foldl'`) and strict `Map`. This means that map of height counts constructed in single pass without [thunks](https://wiki.haskell.org/Thunk).

```
solve heights = map (\ix -> 1 + length (takeWhile (<ix) counts))
  where
    counts = scanl1 (+) $ Map.elems $ count heights
```

I'm using `1 + length (takeWhile (<ix) counts)` instead of bare recursion in `first_gt`.

A bit more code is required for binary search:

```
solve heights = map (maybe 0 snd . (`Map.lookupLT` countsMap))
  where
    counts = scanl1 (+) $ Map.elems $ count heights
    countsMap = Map.fromList $ zip counts [2..]
```

### Vectors as arrays

If `log(n)` overhead of trees is too much for you, it is possible to use `Data.Vector` which is for real arrays in Haskell.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M
import qualified Data.Vector.Algorithms.Search as S

max_height = 200

solve :: [Int] -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
solve heights indices = do
  v <- M.replicate (max_height+1) 0
  mapM_ (M.modify v (+1)) heights
  counts <- V.unsafeFreeze v >>= V.unsafeThaw . V.scanl1' (+)
  mapM (S.binarySearchL counts) indices
```

`binarySearchL` is from [vector-algorithms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Algorithms-Search.html) package.

---

Some utility code to parse input:

```
main = getContents >>= mapM_ print . map (uncurry solve) . parse

parse :: String -> [([Int], [Int])]
parse
  = pairs
  . map
    ( takeWhile (/= 0) -- drop trailing zeroes
    . map read . words -- convert string to ints
    )
  . tail . lines       -- skip first line


pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs (x:y:xs) = (x, y) : pairs xs
pairs _        = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists are not for random access. As far as I know, Vectors are the modern way to have fixed-length random-access listlikes. They will allow you to do the traversing updates you want in one pass.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
counts = V.toList . V.accum (+) (V.replicate 200 0) . map (,1)
```

first_gt doesn't need a manual implementation:

```
import Safe
first_gt e = findIndexJust (> e)
```

And just for fun, this should only traverse the counts result once. (Requires that indices is sorted, though.)

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
solve heights = scanl1 (+) . map length . splitsOnFoo . map (subtract 1) where
  splitsOnFoo = evalState $ traverse (state . span . (<)) $ scanl1 (+) $ counts heights
```